# Recursive traversal of unknown json object/tree and actions based on returned json

Tags: javascript, json, loops, recursion, tree

I'm using a API that returns JSON on request. This JSON has either names for next level URL's or a filename.

The problem is that code has to recognize which JSON is returned.

If JSON only has a names for next url levels then create url and get it.
Then recursively get a new set of names or files, recognize and do it over. It can go as menu levels deep as required. 1 to *

If it has a filename it should get it and render it as html.
(This is already solved)

Example of json

```
{id: 'New_url_1_level_1', id:'New_url_2_level_1', id:'New_url_3_level_1'}
//or
{id:'001200.file.ext',id:'001300.file.ext'...}
```

These would turn into http://my.api.call.com/New_url_1_level_1.../New_url1_level_2/...

The problem is that how to loop over URL's and to finally get to filename for example:
http://my.api.call.com/New_url_1_level_1/New_url_1_level_2/New_url_1_level_3/001300.file.ext

My current script is:

```
 var json;
        var urllevel= '/First_level';
        var api = 'http://my.api.call.com';
        var re = /^\d+/g; // Regex to match filename (decide if json has filenames or urls; files always start with digits or end with extension)

        var loopApiUrl = new Array();
        var recursion = false;
        // This is the problem - how to recursively build url's based on returned data i.e. traverse a "unknown" tree
        function recursePxJson(){
                if (!recursion) {
                    loopApiUrl = [];
                }
// Get JSON
            $.get(api+urllevel+'/'+loopApiUrl.join('/'),function(data,status){

                for (var i in data) {
                    if (!re.test(data[i].id)) { //     {id: 'This_is_to_be_appended_to_url', id:'Another_appendable'}
                        recursion = true;

                        loopApiUrl.push(data[i].id);
                            recursePxJson();

                        }
                        else { //    {id:'001200.file.ext',id:'001300.file.ext'}

                        load(api+urllevel+'/'+loopApiUrl.join('/')+'/'+data[i].id);
                        recursion = false;

                        }
                }

            });    
            //loadDBS(param);
        }

            // Load renderable JSON - ALREADY SOLVED
            function load(param){
            $.get(param, function(data, status){
                json = JSON.stringify(data);
                var title = data.title.split(':');
                html = '<h2>'+title[0]+'</h2>';
                html += '<h3>'+title[1]+'</h3>';
                html += '<h5>Values:</h5>';

                for (var i=0; i<data.variables.length; i++) {
                    html += '<b>'+data.variables[i].text+': </b>';
                    varlen  = data.variables[i].valueTexts.length;
                    if (varlen > 6) {
                        html += '<i>'+data.variables[i].valueTexts[0]+', '+data.variables[i].valueTexts[1]+', '+data.variables[i].valueTexts[2]+' . . . '+data.variables[i].valueTexts[varlen-3]+', '+data.variables[i].valueTexts[varlen-2]+', '+data.variables[i].valueTexts[varlen-1]+'</i>'+'<b> (yhteens&auml; '+varlen+' arvoa)</b>';
                    } else {
                        html += '<i>'+data.variables[i].valueTexts.join(',')+'</i>';
                   }
                    html += '<br/>';

                }

                $(html+'<br>').appendTo($('#tab2'));
            });
            }
```

EDIT: At the moment it seems like it is does each for loop before it begins another. Therefore it starts one in loop and if another is instatiated it won't be run before the fist one is done.

Main loop
    Internal Loop 1
         Internal Loop 2 <- Isn't this the one that should done first?

Comment: your links doesn't work, please provide valid data

Answer (score 0):

1. Handle your `loopApiUrl` variable as a parameter for your function `recursePxJson()`.
2. Get rid of the useless `recursion` boolean.

---

You may find it easier to ditch jQuery and make use of a plain old XMLHTTPRequest. Your code will be slightly longer *but* you'll gain a better control of what your doing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but at least I couldn't get it to work. And I'm afraid that if I used any higher level api i.e. plain old XMLHTTPRequest I would result in even more spaghetti :) Somehow it seems like the "data" is always the same (after jQuery get). And even though it does a new get request it is using the data of the very first response.